# Question about space station physics in Interstellar

Tags: plot-explanation, interstellar

At the end of *Interstellar* when "Cooper Station" is shown orbiting around Saturn, why does the ball while playing baseball travel to a different side and the houses appear to be upside down and there seems to be a "Pipe" effect?

Comment: Please use **descriptive** titles that actually tell viewers what your question is about rather than generic titles.

Comment: Related (and possible duplicate): [What was Interstellar's post-climax scene all about?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27152/49).

Comment: Yes, I agree, the other question (and especially the answer) is a dupe